# Tinymce wraps output in <html> tags instead of <p> tags

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Tinymce wraps output as a full html page instead of wrapping it in paragraph or div tags as html snippets. The code below shows an output stored to database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Which of the numbers from the options is a prime number</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the `fullpage` plugin loaded - if you don't load that plugin TinyMCE will only allow you to work with the content inside the `<body>` and it will only provide the data inside the `<body>` when you submit the form or ask for the content via an API call.